# How to dereference a swig float reference in python?

Tags: python, swig

I use C++ and swig to do some calculations. To simplify it, lets assume it looks like this:

```
struct TestIt{
  TestIt(float x):x(x){};
  inline float& getIt() {return x;};
  float x;
};
```

Now I want to use the the `getIt()` function and print the float value.

With

```
testee = matching.TestIt(42)
print(testee.getIt())
```

I get

```
<Swig Object of type 'float *' at 0x1cb1690>
```

which makes sense, because getIt returns a reference. How can I dereference it/get a python float out of it (without changing the c++ code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn47) and [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn4). You'd write something like this in your SWIG module:

```
%pointer_class(float, floatp)
```

That will let you do this in your Python code:

```
print(testee.getIt().value())
```

You will need to change your SWIG module, or write one if you are swigging the C++ header file directly. But you can probably get away with simply including your C++ header from there.

Comment: The link to [cointer.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_nn4) of the current swig verson (2.0)